# emacs cross-file keyboard macro

Tags: emacs, macros

How would I go about setting up a macro to work across multiple files?

For example, say I have multiple angular apps, and I would like to add an injectable to every single module?

So for every file such that

```
./apps/app-name/index.js
```

I would like to find the first instance of

```
angular.module('module-name', ['list', 'of', 'injectables']);
```

or

```
angular.module('other-module-name', [
  'list',
  'of',
  'injectables']);
```

And add another item onto the end of the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's actually pretty easy<sup>1</sup>

I would start in a single-window frame, and run <kbd>M-x</kbd> `find-name-dired` <kbd>RET</kbd> to generate a dired listing of all the `index.js` files (if I understood that correctly). Or maybe you'd use `find-grep-dired` to list all files containing `angular.module(`. Or `rgrep` if individual matches are more appropriate. Whatever is necessary to generate the links you need to the files of interest.

Then I would start recording the macro (<kbd><f3></kbd>) with point on the first of those files, firstly using <kbd>o</kbd> (from dired; <kbd>RET</kbd> from grep) to open the file in the other window.

Then you would perform your edits, in a sufficiently generic way that the actions will apply for all files being edited.

Finally use <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>o</kbd> to return to the dired listing, then <kbd>C-n</kbd> to move to the next file, whereupon you would stop recording the macro (<kbd><f4></kbd>).

<sup>1</sup> The ease of "casually" creating a keyboard macro to process data split over multiple buffers is one of those things that really drives home the immense power of the feature. The first time it occurred to me that I could *actually do that* was a huge "Aha!" moment for me, and I've been a big fan of keyboard macros ever since.

Comment: This is a great answer.

Answer (score 1):

The solution by Philis is often just what one needs, but unfortunately it reaches its limits if what one wants to do is to execute a keyboard macro "to exhaustion" for all the selected files.  This is because the inner macro rings the bell when it arrives at the end of the buffer and this interrupts the definition of the outer macro.

I proposed a [solution to this problem](https://superuser.com/a/1416309/1010507) on superuser: a command that allows to execute a macro an arbitrary number of times for all files that are selected in a dired buffer.

Comment: Having marked in dired all the files you wanted to process, you could also use `t k` to hide all *other* files from the buffer, and then proceed as usual; or you could use `M-}` in the macro recording to go to the next marked file instead of using `C-n`.

Comment: Oh, I see -- you mean for each file, run a macro on that file until it fails, and *then* move to the next file and repeat...